# Sort order of Django Admin records

Tags: django, django-models

I have followed the Poll tutorial on http://docs.djangoproject.com.

I would like to know if it is possible to add a sort order to the 'Choice' Model when editing a Poll. If so, how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
class SeminarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Seminar
    extra = 0
    ordering = ('-date',)
```

worked for me (above adapted from my model)
It sorted in descending date order

Comment: Both this and @Marcus Whybrow's answer solves the issue. The question is if someone wants to restrict the default sort to only the admin view, or to other views also.

Comment: An interesting problem with this: let's say you order users with: `ordering = ('-last_login',)`, which can be null, i.e. the user never logged in.  But you are interested in the most recent users, so the null `last_login` users appearing ahead of the most recently logged in is quite annoying.

Comment: Someone came up with a solution for the null datetime issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70720056/585783

Answer (score 26):

There is also the possibility to override `get_ordering(self, request)` of the `ModelAdmin` which allows for case insensitive ordering:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    search_fields = ['name']

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return [Lower('name')]  # sort case insensitive
```

Comment: I think that `return [Lower('name')]` should be `return [self.name.lower()]`.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses no, you definitely don't want to lower the field name but the values that are used for sorting.

Comment: Alright, the `import` you added now offers new information.

Comment: Simpler example: Order by created_on field descending: `return ['-created_on']`

Comment: You can also do this with `ordering = (Lower('name'))`

Answer (score 24):

You can add `Meta` options to a Django model which can dictate how it behaves. There is an `ordering` option which defines by which model attribute records should be ordered.

You can find the documentation for the meta ordering option [here in the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering):

Comment: Is this not the answer you are looking for?

Comment: I can see wgar Lylo is saying.. I have the same problem..[a,b,c,d].. I want to be able to let the admin reorder the data without relying on a field.. [d,c,a,b] for example

Comment: Perfect solution! Example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options)

Comment: Beware that this sets the default ordering for the model, not only for the admin. This means it can have performance impact when querying a large number of items in a place where you do not need ordering.

Answer (score 23):

Below is the method as per 4.0 documentation

```
# mymodel/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

# admin.site.register(models.MyModel)

@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['-last_name']
```

Here **last_name** is the field inside **MyModel**.

Comment: Thank you, I had to register the model as shown in your example. Otherwise the filter/order would appear on my other models as well, which throws an error because the field is missing on the other models

Answer (score 9):

For example if you want the table to be sorted by percentage :

1. Go to models.py file in your mainapp
2. ```
   class Meta:
    abstract = True
    ordering = ['-percentage'] #Sort in desc order
   ```
3. ```
   class Meta:
    abstract = True
    ordering = ['percentage'] #Sort in asc order
   ```

Comment: I believe the OP meant ordering the model items in the admin interface ("when editing a Poll"); making the model abstract will prevent its registration with admin.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to define a order within an InlineAdmin django doesn't offer you a a generic solution to do this! There are [some snippets out there](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/) that enable you to add this functionality to the admin, also the [grappelli skin](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/customization.html#inline-sortables) offers you such a feature!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add [ordering to your ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering). This is separated from your models.py ordering.