# Ordering users by date created in django admin panel

Tags: python, django

How do you order users in the django admin panel so that upon display they are ordered by date created? Currently they are listed in alphabetical order

I know that I can import the `User` model via: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571916/django-admin-sort-order

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To change the default ordering of users in admin panel you can subclass the default UserAdmin class. In your applications's `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # override the default sort column
    ordering = ('date_joined', )
    # if you want the date they joined or other columns displayed in the list,
    # override list_display too
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'date_joined', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')

# finally replace the default UserAdmin with yours
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

For more information refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/).

Comment: Ok, I'll try creating an admin.py file in main project directory

Comment: Created an admin.py in main project directory; nothing happened.

Comment: Sorry, naming mistake, corrected in my answer - not in your project directory, in your application's directory (`your_project/your_app_name/admin.py`).

Comment: This is where it is and same thing happens: `webapp/mysite/admin.py`

Comment: The example is tested in one of my project using Django 1.10 (copied and pasted) so I can guarantee it works, one possibility may be that `django.contrib.admin` is misconfigured in your project, please refer to the documentation I linked in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Django 1.7. I'll debug via the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: I just added the logic to a random app file and it worked. I thought it made sense to add it to the main app folder too (`webapp/mysite/admin.py`), but nothing happens when it's added there.

Comment: @JohnSmith, did you ever figure this out? I'm using Django 1.8 and seeing the same thing as you. It works when I add the code to an app's admin.py, but not when I create an ```admin.py``` in ```webapp/mysite/``` directory. I confirmed each step of the admin setup in the docs.

Comment: @JohnSmith I had a hunch and it turned out to be correct. By default it doesn't look like Django considers ```mysite``` an app. I created a vanilla project to test this theory, and creating ```webapp/mysite/admin.py``` with a change to User ordering did nothing, but then I added ```mysite``` to the list of ```INSTALLED_APPS``` and that did it. It doesn't seem like Django wants you to do this since they don't include ```mysite``` by default, so maybe it's better to create a bare app to hold the ```Auth``` model overrides? Cheers!

Comment: use `ordering = ('-date_joined', )` if you want desc order

Answer (score 2):

The admin site will default to the ordering specified on your model itself, e.g.

```
class MyUserModel:
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )
```

If you want something more flexible, that is, if you want to use Django default user model without [subclassing it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

--

Edit: While what I say is not wholly incorrect, @rafalmp's answer is the right one.