# Django admin: order by a nullable date, with null values at the end

Tags: django

I have a model with a DateTimeField which I would like to use to order the table in admin. Using `ordering = ('-completed',)` in `admin.py` works, but those with `null` values come first in the sort. Is there a way to make them appear at the end instead?

So at the moment I have something like:

```
Column A     Completed       Column C
x            -               y
x            -               y
x            Today's date    y
x            Yesterday's     y
```

Is there a way to make it like this?

```
Column A     Completed       Column C
x            Today's date    y
x            Yesterday's.    y
x            -               y
x            -               y
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can  use query expressions. To order by  completed ascending and make null values sort last, use this:

```
from django.db.models import F

ordering = [F('completed').desc(nulls_last=True)]
```

Source :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! The code doesn't work because of the minus sign before `completed` but this alternative does: `ordering = [F('completed').desc(nulls_last=True)]`